# From a glass jar with $N$ balls - $M$ blue and $N-M$ red we take $n$ balls out without returning them.

Tags: probability

Consider a glass jar with $N$ balls, $M$ of which are blue and $N-M$ of which are red.

We take $n$ balls out *without* returning them.
Let $X$ be the Random variable that represents how many blue balls are taken out.

Then, the probability mass function for $X$ is $$p_X(m) = \binom{M}{m}\binom{N-M}{n-m}\,/\,\binom{N}{n}.$$

Why is this true? I feel like we are not taking into account that balls are *not* being returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of taking out exactly $m$ blue balls is equivalent to the probability of permuting the finite sequence
$$
\underbrace{B\cdots B}_{M\text{ times}}\overbrace{R\cdots R}^{N-M\text{ times}}
$$
so that there are exactly $m$ letter $B$s among the first $n$ elements (assuming a uniform distribution over all permutations).
The number of such permutations is
$$
\text{num_relevant_permutations}\equiv\binom{n}{m}\binom{N-n}{M-m}.
$$
The total number of possible permutations is
$$
\text{num_permutations}\equiv\binom{N}{M}.
$$
Some simple algebra should let you check that
$$
\text{num_relevant_permutations}\,/\,\text{num_permutations}.
$$
is equivalent to the expression for $p_X(m)$ you provided.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But i still dont understand one point , i feel like the solution for this question would be the same with out the requirement to NOT return the balls after taking them out?

Comment: No, if you replace the ball after drawing it, the solution is a binomial distribution. In particular, 
$$
p_{X}(m)\equiv\binom{n}{m}q^{m}\left(1-q\right)^{n-m}\text{ where }q=M/N.
$$

Comment: Thank you , I understand it much better now !